# Pop os default app drawer folders keeps coming after reboot

Tags: pop-os

Pop os default app drawer folders keeps coming back after every reboot.

Even when I am deleting every time.

Thanks

[image].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.